# How to access RDS instance which is public subnet and publicly accessible from ec2 instance in other VPC's private subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I have 2 VPC. VPC A and VPC B, VPC A is the default VPC in which I have one publicly accessible RDS instance and in  VPC B I have ec2 instance in the private subnet. When I try to connect from  ec2 instance in private subnet from VPC B to public RDS instance running in default VPC A, I am not able to connect but for private RDS running default in VPC A, I am able to connect from ec2 instance running in private subnet of VPC B

What should I do inorder to allow application running in private subnet or pubilc subnet in VPC-2  to connect to mysql public rds instance running public subnet.

Comment: Your question is confusing. For example, what do you mean by "ec2 instance under private vpc"? What is a 'private VPC'? Do you mean a private subnet in the VPC? What is a 'private EC2 instance'? Do you mean an instance running in a private subnet? Please edit your question to more clearly explain what you have in each VPC and what works/does not work.

Comment: Yes I do mean private subnet in the VPC

Comment: So you are saying that you can connect from the EC2 instance to a private RDS database in VPC A? How is this possible? Have you configured VPC Peering?

Comment: VPC peering is already configured. I was able to resolve issue, We had set IP restrictions in security group of Public RDS in VPC A. I just added NAT Gateway's IP to security group and was able to connect  from EC2 instance in private subnet of VPC B to public RDS instance in VPC A. Thanks @JohnRotenstein